# Getting all possible combinations from a List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, list, recursion, skip

I call this function in order to get a `List<List<Card>>`:

```cs
List<List<Card>> comboCards = GetComboCards(new List<Card>(), board, new List<List<Card>>());

private List<List<Card>> GetComboCards(List<Card> previous, List<Card> board, List<List<Card>> combos)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < board.Count; i++)
    {
        Card card = board[i];
        List<Card> newPrevious = previous.Skip(i).ToList(); //  FIXME: Not right
        newPrevious.Add(card);
        combos.Add(newPrevious);
        List<Card> newBoard = board.Skip(i + 1).ToList();
        GetComboCards(newPrevious, newBoard, combos);
    }

    return combos;
}
```

There's a problem with `previous.Skip(i).ToList()` which I'm unsure of how to correct.

---

**Example:**

Board contains 4 cards. When run through GetComboCards, the List will return the appropriate number of `List<Card>`'s (15). However the List will have duplicates of the same combination in [5] and [12] for the 3rd card and again in [7], [11], and [14] for the 4th card.

---

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I know it has to do with the line where I've added FIXME, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `Skip(n)` will skip n values.  If you want all the values except the one at index n you'd do `list.Take(n).Concat(list.Skip(n+1))`

Comment: When you need to eliminate duplicates, you should take a look at: [LINQ's Distinct() on a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)